# Custom R distribution with specific packages included

Tags: r, package

How does one create a custom distribution of R, with core R and a few specific packages/libraries to make it fully self-contained for a user. I want to create a custom R distribution such that it has R and the packages required for the NLME which a user can easily download and install without having to download and install individual packages.

Comment: What operating system will you and the other users be using?

Comment: If I can be a bit broad, I would say across any *nix but very specifically RHEL4.

Answer (score 0):

See the ['R Installation and Administration' manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html), it shows how to build and install R for various operating systems. You could include extra packages in the library of the build.

Comment: Which section? There is the piece to control what gets loaded when R starts up and there is the piece about installing new packages. But I dont seem to find anything about creating a source code packaging which will include base R and a few specific packages.